# If we change `git config core.hooksPath`, how to revert back to default

Tags: git, githooks, git-config

By default, it looks like this is empty when run in a git repo root:

```
git config core.hooksPath
```

If we change git config core.hooksPath to `git config core.hooksPath myhooks`, my question is - how do we change it back to the default? Should we unset the value (how?), or should we set it to `.git/hooks` as in `git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks`?

Comment: Have you tried `git config --unset core.hooksPath`?

Comment: sure unset would probably work, and if it's not set, then git would default to .git/hooks

Comment: You can also delete the your customized settings under `[core]` in `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer depends on where it's set and what you want to change. If the option is set in your local repository and you want to undo it, then `git config --unset core.hooksPath` is sufficient to unset it, which will make Git pick the default option.

If the option is set in a higher level configuration (e.g., per-user or per-system) and you don't want to remove it from that location, only override it for this repository, you can use `git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks` if you are in a non-bare repository or `git config core.hooksPath hooks` if you are in a bare repository.

From `git-config(1)`:

> The path can be either absolute or relative. A relative path is taken as relative to the directory where the hooks are run.

From `githooks(5)`:

> Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either $GIT_DIR in a bare repository or the root of the working tree in a non-bare repository.

Hence the requirement for `.git/hooks` in a non-bare repository and `hooks` in a bare one.